# How to find out missing column names in InventoryItem table

Tags: acumatica

We have created a custom process screen which updates data in ARTran table, we are also making bql call to InventoryItem table to check some conditions.

The issue is we are getting error, some of the InventoryItem table fields are missing and these are standard Acumatica fields and these are exists in InventoryItem table in database.

See the below image:

[image]

Comment: Those column names are invalid in the SQL database in standard Acumatica 2019R2, and I do not remember them as far back as 2018R1.  If you added them, they should have started with Usr to comply with the standard naming convention for user added fields.  Once you add the fields, you also must add them in the DAC.  If these are defined in the DAC as PXDB fields, change the definition to just PXInt, PXString, etc.

Comment: Hi Brain, we are using 2019 R1 build 19.106.0020, we compared all our custom database fields we created and they do have DAC fields declared, any other thoughts please

Comment: Since none of those fields exist in my instance of the database, I have to assume they were added to yours for you, but so many that say "Note" seems odd because notes are tied to the NoteID (GUID type) field normally.  A custom field should start with Usr, but the error itself indicates that the field is NOT in the database as believed.  If it was not in the DAC, reference to the fields would prevent compiling in the first place.  Reference in the DAC but not the database would allow compile but generate run-time errors.  Can you post your DAC Extension showing these fields?

Answer (score 0):

These fields are Not the default Acumatica fields in 19.106.0020 version.

It's strange, as @Brian Stevens indicated if a field created by us then that field name will have a prefix as **Usr**.

As these fields exist in the InventoryItem DAC extension but NOT the database, hence we are getting this run time error.

Even after publishing the package, if you still facing this issue, then that package does not contain the Inventoryitem DAC extension fields. Add these fields to the database and add it to the package.

Please post us the Inventory DAC extension, which will help us to identify the root cause.